# Pandas: How to aggregate a column with multiple functions and add the results as other columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like:

```
   A  B 
0  1  1 
1  1  2 
2  2  3 
3  2  4
```

I want to add min of B and max of B as new columns named `minB` and `maxB`.

Expected

```
   A  minB maxB 
0  1  1    2 
1  2  3    4
```

Comment: Can you also please post your expected output?

Comment: You are looking for [Named Aggregation](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation).

Comment: @MayankPorwal I modified the question. I had some mistakes and I modified the whole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Named Aggregation](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```py
df.groupby("A", as_index=False).agg(
    minB=("B", "min"),
    maxB=("B", "max")
)
```

Comment: What if I want to keep a column with its name like what I do in `"D":"mean"` in dictionary format? Can I mix this format with dictionary ones for `agg`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.min`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) & [`numpy.max`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
In [472]: import numpy as np

In [473]: df.groupby('A').agg({'B':[np.min, np.max]}).reset_index()
Out[473]: 
   A    B     
     amin amax
0  1    1    2
1  2    3    4
```